# How can i exec a stored procedure and select from its temp table in visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio, sql-server-2008-r2

I have this sp ˋUpdate_driver_Positionˋ with a parameter ˋtemptblˋ (varchar type), in the sp i select other table's data into ˋtemptblˋ. i know how to run sp in visual studio but i don't know how to select data from ˋtemptblˋ(get the date in temptbl to sqldatareader).

This is how i run the sp in SQL Server

```
 Exec dbo.Update_Driver_Position '##Temp'
 Select * From ##Temp
```

This is my code in visual studio

```
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
        {

            string text = "Update_driver_Position";
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            cmd.CommandText = text;
            SqlParameter retval = cmd.Parameters.Add("@Temptbl", SqlDbType.VarChar);
            retval.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;


            cmd.Connection = this.GetConnection();
            cmd.Connection.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            SqlDataReader reader = (cmd.Parameters["@Temptbl"]);

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                //...
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem Solved!
Here's my code:

```
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
        {

            string text = string.Format("Exec dbo.Update_Driver_Position '##Temp' Select * From ##Temp");
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            cmd.CommandText = text;



            cmd.Connection = this.GetConnection();
            cmd.Connection.Open();


            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
               //...
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you saying how to I get column data from the returned reader into say av

`int x = (int)reader["MyField"];`

Or how to store the data into the reader?  You need to make a call to `ExecuteReader()`.
`SqlDataReader r = cmdSproc.ExecuteReader();`

Here is some sample code:

```
 using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connString))
            {
                //use sproc
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("selMyProcedure", con);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                 //some paramters
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@VendorName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = vn;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@ProductTypeName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = pt;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@ProductName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = p;
                con.Open();
                  //you need to add below
                SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();


                while (reader.Read())
                {
                   int x = (int)reader["MyCol"];
                }
//...more code
```

In other words you need to assign a reader the command object applied to `ExecuteReader()`.
And once you have the data in the reader you can read it by: `reader["MyColumn"]`.

Comment: I know that, how can i pass '##temptbl' to stored procedure cause with cmd.Parameters.Add("@VendorName", SqlDbType.VarChar) we add parameter not temp table.